# Связать результаты <form> с графиком на Google Charts

Tags: javascript, html, google-chart

Есть простой график на Google Charts:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Time', 'First', 'Second'],
      ['00',         4,        4],
      ['01',         7,        7],
      ['02',         6,        6],
      ['03',         5,        6]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Chart online',
      hAxis: {title: 'Время',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
      vAxis: {minValue: 0}
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);

  }
</script>
```

И есть форма:

```
<form name="in">
    <input name="data">
    <input type="button" value="ok" onClick="ab();">
</form>
```

Как мне передавать результаты ввода в массив с данными для отрисовки графиком? Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот и вторая реализация на котором не добавляются строки а меняются:

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    let chart;
    let data;
    let options;
    function drawChart() {
     data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
       ['Time', 'First', 'Second'],
       ['00',         4,        4],
       ['01',         7,        7],
       ['02',         6,        6],
       ['03',         5,        6]
     ]);

     options = {
       title: 'Chart online',
       hAxis: {title: 'Время',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
       vAxis: {minValue: 0}
     };

     chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
     chart.draw(data, options);
     
    }
    function drawChartRow(){
     let row_id = parseInt(document.querySelector("input[name='Time']").value);
     let row_Time = document.querySelector("input[name='Time']").value;
     let row_First = parseInt(document.querySelector("input[name='First']").value);
     let row_Second = parseInt(document.querySelector("input[name='Second']").value);
     
     
     if(row_id >= data.qg.length){
      data.addRows([
       [row_Time, row_First, row_Second]
      ]);
     }
     else{
      data.removeRow(row_id);
      data.insertRows(row_id, [[row_Time, row_First, row_Second]]);
     }
     
     chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
     chart.draw(data, options);     
     return false;
    }
    
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
  <form name="in">
   <input name="Time" value="00" />
   <input name="First" value="10" />
   <input name="Second" value="8" />
   <input type="button" value="ok" onclick="drawChartRow()">
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Здесь использованы методы `removeRow` `insertRows`. То есть удаляем строку и в место нее добавляем новую с новыми значениями.

Фишка кода в том что если в форме `input` написать существующий номер то строка обновится а если номер больше чем есть на графике то оно добавит новую строку методом `addRows`.

А для пустого графика инициализируй `google charts api` вот так с нулевыми значениями:

```
data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Time', 'First', 'Second'],
  ['00',         0,        0],
  ['01',         0,        0],
  ['02',         0,        0],
  ['03',         0,        0]
]);
```

Comment: @Pavel Вам так было нужно?

Answer (score 3):

Добрый день. Вот мой пример реализации задуманного.

Объясняю что я сделал. В `Google Charts` Есть метод `addRows`. При клике на `submit button` формы я вызвал метод `addRows` и добавил в опции графика новую строку. Но для того что бы оно было видно в графике надо с ново инициализировать график. И что бы старые данные не потерять я сделал переменные в функции `drawChart()` глобальными. и после каждого клика на `submit` к старым опциям добавляется новая строка и график инициализируется с ново.

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    let chart;
    let data;
    let options;
    function drawChart() {
    data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Time', 'First', 'Second'],
      ['00',         4,        4],
      ['01',         7,        7],
      ['02',         6,        6],
      ['03',         5,        6]
    ]);

    options = {
      title: 'Chart online',
      hAxis: {title: 'Время',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
      vAxis: {minValue: 0}
    };

    chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);

    }
    function drawChartRow(){
     data.addRows([
      [document.querySelector("input[name='Time']").value,
       parseInt(document.querySelector("input[name='First']").value),
       parseInt(document.querySelector("input[name='Second']").value)
      ]
     ]);
     chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
     chart.draw(data, options);     
     return false;
    }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
  <form name="in">
   <input name="Time" value="04" />
   <input name="First" value="10" />
   <input name="Second" value="8" />
   <input type="button" value="ok" onclick="drawChartRow()">
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Вы решили это через добавление новых столбцов, а есть способ не добавлять новые а присваивать новые значения старым? То есть ситуация когда количество столбцов фиксированно бизнес-логикой просто этот график показывает активность в течении суток, а так получиться в сутках будет столько часов сколько мы добавим...

Comment: Попробую и это реализовать.

Comment: буду очень признателен, видать пора мне ментора по js искать...

Comment: @Pavel вы хотите менять всегда определенную строку или все строки?

Comment: да я хочу менять только одну строку тоесть я ввожу какой кгафик я хочу поменять и точку во времени к которой я меняю. На пример на 1 час для First устанавливаю такое-то значение. А часов на графике у меня 24 вне зависимости от запонености. Если ничего не заполнено то просто пустой график я еще столкнулся с тем что если на графике еще нет данных то он вообще не отрисовывается пока не как не победить эту проблему.

Comment: а вы учеников не берете?

Comment: @Pavel в профиле есть контакт `linkedin`.