# Изменить высоту грида

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, html5-canvas

У меня проблема с канвасом html5. У меня есть датасэт для заполнения графика в канвасе по данным из базы. Как выставить высоту грида больше на одно деление. Должно выглядеть примерно так:
[image: Примерный вид моего канваса (просто как пример, картинка не моя)]

Мой вариант:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно сделать грид как сдесь, где верхняя точка 50С, но есть расстояния до самих графиков сверху. Как мне сделать такой же оффсет? Так как у меня крайняя точка это максимальное значение из базы, т.е. у меня график начинался бы не с 50С, а с 40С. И верхняя точка задрана кверху, что не очень хорошо выгляжит. Я надеюсь моё объяснение не сильно "пространное".

Код:

```
$('#graf_' + i + '').html('<canvas id="lineChart' + i + '" width="' + $(".graf").width() + '" height="200"></canvas>');

var lineData = {
        labels: data["headers"],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: data["rates"][i]["VltName"],
                fillColor: "transparent",
                strokeColor: data["rates"][i]["VltColor"],
                pointColor: data["rates"][i]["VltColor"],
                pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                data: getRatesArr
            }
        ]
    };
    var lineOptions = {
        scaleShowGridLines: true,
        scaleGridLineColor: "rgba(0,0,0,.05)",
        scaleGridLineWidth: 1,
        bezierCurve: false,
        pointDot: true,
        pointDotRadius: 4,
        pointDotStrokeWidth: 1,
        pointHitDetectionRadius: 20,
        datasetStroke: true,
        datasetStrokeWidth: 2,
        datasetFill: true
    };

var ctx = document.getElementById("lineChart" + i).getContext("2d");
var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineData, lineOptions);
```

Comment: Можете сказать какой `api`  вы используете для графика?

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan Canvas API

Comment: А вам подойдет решение с `google charts api` ?

Comment: Пример вот тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/677585/Связать-результаты-form-с-графиком-на-google-charts/677666